# OAM packets are lost in linux kernel IP stack

Tags: ip

I would like to have your suggestion/comment on a particular issue i am facing right now.This issue is observed on port mirroring configured at the same host while the port mirroring at remote end is working fine.

## Setup description:

OAM packet in UDP are send and received by two threads one for each.
The OAM packet is send to the remote end through ethernet, while during the traverse of this OAM packet in IP stack, a **OUTPUT hook** is applied(as shown below), which will clone the outgoing OAM packet for mirroring purpose.

```
iptables  -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d 172.25.62.55/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 16 --port 33  -j oam_mirror --ip 172.25.62.38 --cid 33
```

In the above rule, `172.25.62.55` is remote IP and `172.25.62.38` is localhost IP.

## My debugging and observation:

I can verify that the OAM packet is cloned and left in the stack (using `ip_send_check(iph); dst->output(nskb);`) to reach at the receiving end (cloned `pkt src IP = 172.25.62.38, dst IP = 172.25.62.38`) correctly but this cloned OAM packet is not receiving at the receiving thread on the same host.

I think from my observation after debugging this scenario is that the OAM packet is not routed to local IP deliver and lost the packet after oam_mirror hook. It is very difficult to debug this packet in IP stack on restrictive system.

I am stuck here and unable to go anywhere from now, can anyone please suggest me,how to proceed further from here. It would be very helpful if you provide some solution for this particular issue.

Please feel free to ask if you need more information on this.

Comment: Maybe try to ask on : https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/